# plotroc.py Error in libSVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying to run [plotroc.py](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/roc/plotroc.py) from libSVM But I am having some error message popping up, I did the compilation of the library so I do have it and the call to it is right

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotroc.py", line 3, in <module>
    from svmutil import *
  File "libsvm-master/python/svmutil.py", line 5, in <module>
    from svm import *
  File "libsvm-master/python/svm.py", line 303, in <module>
    fillprototype(libsvm.svm_get_sv_indices, None, [POINTER(svm_model), POINTER(c_int)])
  File "/opt/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/opt/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: libsvm-master/python/../libsvm.so.2: undefined symbol: svm_get_sv_indices
```

Can you please point me to the source of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

For linux system only:

Download libsvm.zip package. Unzip it to find directory named "python". This directory must be having files like svmutil.py , Makefile, svm.py

run "make" command ..

paste your plotroc.py script in that directory

./plotroc.py